# add circle div on a picture

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add some circles with a text on a picture.

In fullscreen mode there is no problem, but when i resize the window the circles are moving rather than staying to their positions.

Code :

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto;width: 100%;">
    <img src="http://www.gimpfr.org/document/document_10/images/straight_line_example.png" width="600" height="500" alt="top" style="position:absolute;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;left: 0;right: 0;">
    <div style="-webkit-border-radius:100px;-moz-border-radius:100px;-o-border-radius:100px;border-radius:100px;width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;position: absolute;margin-left:60%"></div>
    <div style="-webkit-border-radius:100px;-moz-border-radius:100px;-o-border-radius:100px;border-radius:100px;width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;position: absolute;margin-left:40%;margin-top:15%;"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it with only css or should i use jquery or something like that ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?  The reason I ask is that it sounds like your question would best be solved by using an SVG or Canvas container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set correct positioning. Main div can be relative or absolute, the circles then are absolute.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5nfjdgLL/1/
The circles are holding position. You can resize your window or resize the panel of output of jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
   <div class=container>
      <img src=http://www.gimpfr.org/document/document_10/images/straight_line_example.png>
      <div class=circle1></div>
       <div class=circle2></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  position:relative; margin: auto; width:478px; height:308px;
  }
  .circle1, .circle2 {background:red; width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:10px;}
  .circle1{position:absolute; top:10px; left:300px;}
  .circle2{position:absolute; top:50px; left:200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your browser is up to date, I would suggest using a `<canvas>` container.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://linktoyourimage.jpg';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `drawImage()` method takes a container variable, and the destination point where you'd like to place the image.

To add circles, you'll need to add some more code:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();
```

That will add a circle in your canvas, based on the center X,Y position with a given radius.  You'll need to create those variables.

As a side note, [Canvas Tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) has some good reference information if you're starting off with html5-specific tags.

Comment: I cant try it atm, but thanks for the answer.
I will try to implement it when i can